# How to set conditional properties?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Kotlin and using Jetpack Compose I have lots of code like:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .requiredWidth(expandedSize)
        .align(Alignment.Center)
)
```

But a lot of time I would like to set a property depending on a condition:

```kotlin
if(isFlag){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .requiredWidth(expandedSizeA)
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
} else {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .requiredWidth(expandedSizeB)
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

or conditions like either `requiredWidth()` or `padding()`

```kotlin
if(isFlag){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .requiredWidth(expandedSizeA)
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
} else {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(80.dp, 30.dp, 80.dp, 0.dp)
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

I would bet there is an elegant Kotlin way to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For you first case, you can use `if` statement inside `requiredWidth`:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .requiredWidth(if(isFlag) expandedSizeA else expandedSizeB)
        .align(Alignment.Center)
)
```

For the second case, use `let` or `run`.

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .run {
            if(isFlag) requiredWidth(expandedSizeA)
            else padding(80.dp, 30.dp, 80.dp, 0.dp)
        }
        .align(Alignment.Center)
)
```

And actually there's a third case as well when you want to either apply or ignore a particular Modifier based on a condition. You can do this with the `let` or `run` statements but using an extension function can make the code a little cleaner.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.modifyIf(condition: Boolean, modify: Modifier.() -> Modifier) = 
    if (condition) modify() else this
```

Usage:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .modifyIf(featureIsEnabled) {
            clickable(onClick = handleClick)
        }
        .padding(24.dp)
)
```

Here the box will be clickable if `featureIsEnabled` is true, otherwise not.

Comment: I love the modifyIf concept! So much cleaner then the run option